# Deduce the Missing Terms in the Sequence

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

$NINE$ + $5$

$EIGHT$ + $3$

$SEVEN$ + $2$

$???$ + $?$

$FIVE$ + $1$

$????$ + $?$

$?????$ -$?$

$???$ - $?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer

> $SIX + 3$
>  $FOUR + 0$
>  $THREE - 2$
>  $TWO - 1$

Reasoning

> Of course, the words themselves are simply counting down from 9. The number of letters, plus or minus the number afterwards, equals the number represented by the word.